# 3D geometry (a bit thoughtful)

Tags: solid-geometry

When we are actually finding the eqn of a plane parallel to the x axis or any other axis then why do we make the direction ratio of respective axis to be zero ?
I mean  for example, you represent for a plane parallel to x axis as by+cz=d where a=0 but why?

Comment: In simple terms: if $(x,y,z)$ belongs to the plane, so does $(x',y,z)$, for any $x'$. This translates to the fact that $x$ cannot appear in the plane equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficients $a,b,c$ in the equation of your plane can be interpreted as the direction cosines of the normal vector to the plane.

Direction cosines are a slightly more general version of the idea of "slope" in 2 variables. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine

By virtue of the normal being perpendicular to the required plane, the corresponding direction coefficient vanishes.

Comment: i understood what you are saying as  cos(90) is zero that's why the normal's direction cosine with x axis is 0 and that's why the term vanishes!!